# How to know if the running platform is Ubuntu or CentOS with help of a Bash script?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I know the commands to check the name of the Linux machine running on my machine. For example:

#### Ubuntu

```
cat /etc/version
```

#### CentOS

```
cat /etc/issue
```

How do I get the output from the terminal and compare to see if it is UBUNTU or CENTOS and perform the following commands?

```
apt-get install updates
```

or

```
yum update
```

#### Ubuntu 14.04

```
cat /etc/issue
```

Answer (score 90, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no surefire, simple way of getting the distribution name. Most major distros [are moving towards](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/92218/22222) a system where they use `/etc/os-release` to store this information. Most modern distributions also include the `lsb_release` tools but these are not always installed by default. So, here are some approaches you can use:

1. Use `/etc/os-release`

   ```
   awk -F= '/^NAME/{print $2}' /etc/os-release
   ```
2. Use the `lsb_release` tools if available

   ```
   lsb_release -d | awk -F"\t" '{print $2}'
   ```
3. Use a more complex script that should work for the great majority of distros:

   ```
   # Determine OS platform
   UNAME=$(uname | tr "[:upper:]" "[:lower:]")
   # If Linux, try to determine specific distribution
   if [ "$UNAME" == "linux" ]; then
       # If available, use LSB to identify distribution
       if [ -f /etc/lsb-release -o -d /etc/lsb-release.d ]; then
           export DISTRO=$(lsb_release -i | cut -d: -f2 | sed s/'^\t'//)
       # Otherwise, use release info file
       else
           export DISTRO=$(ls -d /etc/[A-Za-z]*[_-][rv]e[lr]* | grep -v "lsb" | cut -d'/' -f3 | cut -d'-' -f1 | cut -d'_' -f1)
       fi
   fi
   # For everything else (or if above failed), just use generic identifier
   [ "$DISTRO" == "" ] && export DISTRO=$UNAME
   unset UNAME
   ```
4. Parse the version info of `gcc` if installed:

   *CentOS 5.x*

   ```
   $ gcc --version
   gcc (GCC) 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-54)
   Copyright (C) 2006 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
   ```

   *CentOS 6.x*

   ```
   $ gcc --version
   gcc (GCC) 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-3)
   Copyright (C) 2010 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
   ```

   *Ubuntu 12.04*

   ```
   $ gcc --version
   gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3
   Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
   ```

   *Ubuntu 14.04*

   ```
   $ gcc --version
   gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) 4.8.2
   Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
   This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
   warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
   ```

This has basically been directly copied from @slm's great [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/92218/22222) to my question [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/92199/22222).

Comment: "Unfortunately, there is no surefire, simple way of getting the distribution name." `<—` **This is not the case at all.** [Sylvain Pineau](https://askubuntu.com/users/32239/sylvain-pineau), for example, exhibited a [trivial one-liner](https://askubuntu.com/a/459406/415719) reliably querying the current platform type by deferring to Python – which comes preinstalled on most platforms (including Ubuntu). Shell scripts should *never* attempt to manually query  platform metadata with low-level, non-portable tests of the sort implemented in this answer.

Comment: Gawk is not installed in Debian by default.

Comment: @VilleLaitila I'm afraid that's not relevant here since this site is only about Ubuntu. But there's nothing gawk-specific here, so `awk` or `mawk` or ay other implementation would work just as well.

Comment: Even more specific using `lsb_release`: `lsb_release -d | awk -F"\t" '{print $2}' | awk -F " " '{print $1}'`

Comment: @NerdOfCode if you just want the release number, do `lsb_release -d | awk '{print $3}'` or `grep -oP 'VERSION="\K\S+' /etc/os-release`, no need for the double pipe to awk.

Comment: @terdon Oops... Wasn't thinking.

Comment: The script in 2 also works well on mingw/msys2 and macos - fyi

Answer (score 26):

You don't need bash to do such task, and I'd suggest using a high-level approach to avoid dealing with files like `/etc/version` and `/etc/issue` (I don't have /etc/version on 13.10).

So my recommendation is to use this command instead:

```
python -mplatform | grep -qi Ubuntu && sudo apt-get update || sudo yum update
```

python [platform](https://docs.python.org/2.6/library/platform.html) module will work on both systems, the rest of the command will check if Ubuntu is returned by python and run `apt-get` else `yum`.

Comment: add `-i` to `grep` may help.

Comment: This does not seem to work anymore for Ubuntu 20.04 (I got `Linux-5.4.0-26-generic-x86_64-with-glibc2.29`).

Comment: @wilsonzlin This still works on Python 2.7 but not on Python3.

Answer (score 11):

Check for Ubuntu in the kernel name:

```
if [  -n "$(uname -a | grep Ubuntu)" ]; then
    sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade 
else
    yum update
fi
```

Answer (score 10):

Here's a simple answer that I find works across all versions of Ubuntu / CentOS / RHEL by the mere presence of the files (not failsafe of course if someone is randomly dropping /etc/redhat-release on your Ubuntu boxes, etc):

```
if [ -f /etc/redhat-release ]; then
  yum update
fi

if [ -f /etc/lsb-release ]; then
  apt-get update
fi
```

Comment: on my ubuntu there is no /etc/lsb-release

Comment: I'm not going to -1, but this answer is not correct in at least one case: `/etc/lsb-release` exists on CloudLinux (CentOS) 6.8 so it will return both `yum` and `apt-get`.

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 has `/etc/lsb-release` in package `base-files` and `/usr/bin/lsb_release` in package `lsb-release`.

Comment: Manjaro has `/etc/lsb-release` and does not have apt-get

Answer (score 7):

The [`lsb_release`](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/LSB_3.0.0/LSB-PDA/LSB-PDA/lsbrelease.html) command was added to the Linux Standard Base (ISO/IEC 23360) for this purpose:

```
$ lsb_release -si
Ubuntu
$ lsb_release -sd
Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
$ lsb_release -sr
18.04
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
Release:        18.04
Codename:       bionic
```

Therefore a case statement along the lines of

```
case "`/usr/bin/lsb_release -si`" in
  Ubuntu) echo 'This is Ubuntu Linux' ;;
       *) echo 'This is something else' ;; 
esac
```

should do what you want.

On newer Linux distributions based on systemd there is also [/etc/os-release](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/os-release.html), which is intended to be included into shell scripts with the source (.) command, as in

```
. /etc/os-release

case "$ID" in
  ubuntu) echo 'This is Ubuntu Linux' ;;
       *) echo 'This is something else' ;; 
esac
```

But in the use-case example you gave, you may actually be more interested not in the name of the distribution, but whether it has `apt-get` or `yum`. You could just test for the presence of the files `/usr/bin/apt-get` or `/usr/bin/yum` with `if [ -x /usr/bin/apt-get ]; then` ... or for the presence of associated infrastructure directories, such as `/var/lib/apt` and `/etc/apt/`.

Answer (score 6):

```
 apt-get -v &> /dev/null && apt-get update
 which yum &> /dev/null && yum update
```

if there are only two distro, then you can make it shorter:

```
apt-get -v &> /dev/null && apt-get update || yum update
```

somehow `yum -v` return non-zero in CentOS so use `which` instead,
of course you should consider scenario if there is no `which` installed.

Answer (score 5):

Use [Chef](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chef_%28software%29) for these tasks .;-)

In Chef, you can use the [`platform?`](http://docs.opscode.com/dsl_recipe_method_platform.html) method:

```
if platform?("redhat", "centos", "fedora")
  # Code for only Red Hat Linux family systems.
end
```

Or:

```
if platform?("ubuntu")
  # Code for only Ubuntu systems
end
```

Or:

```
if platform?("ubuntu")
  # Do Ubuntu things
end
```

Or:

```
if platform?("freebsd", "openbsd")
  # Do BSD things
end
```

Comment: While demonstrably superior to [low-level shell-centric fragile non-solutions](https://askubuntu.com/a/459425/415719) (e.g., `lsb_release`, `/etc/os-release`), this solution has the distinct disadvantage of requiring Chef – a heavyweight Infrastructure as Code (IaC) framework *not* installed by default on most platforms and requiring use of its own domain-specific language (DSL). In short, most users probably just want to [defer to Python](https://askubuntu.com/a/459406/415719), which *is* installed by default on most platforms (including Ubuntu) and interfaces well with shell scripting.

Answer (score 2):

The following script should tell if it is Ubuntu. If it is not and the only other option you have is CentOS, you should have it in an `else` clause:

```
dist=`grep DISTRIB_ID /etc/*-release | awk -F '=' '{print $2}'`

if [ "$dist" == "Ubuntu" ]; then
  echo "ubuntu"
else
  echo "not ubuntu"
fi
```

Comment: This can probably be simplified using the `lsb_release` tool, which should read out the same files. `lsb_release -i` reports either `Distributor ID: Ubuntu` or `Distributor ID: CentOS` in these cases.

Comment: @chronitis: yes, sure it can be

Comment: I don't think it's available by default on Centos though

Answer (score 1):

Execute `/etc/os-release` in a sub shell and echo its value:

```
if [ "$(. /etc/os-release; echo $NAME)" = "Ubuntu" ]; then
  apt-get install updates 
else
  yum update
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

lsb_release command is only work for Ubuntu platform but not in centos
so you can get details from /etc/os-release file

following command will give you the both OS name and version-

```
cat /etc/os-release | awk -F '=' '/^PRETTY_NAME/{print $2}' | tr -d '"'

# output :-
# for centos -> CentOS Linux 7 (Core)
# for ubuntu -> Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS (version differ with different releases)
```

You can also get the os name and version separately.
in your case to run update command you can use following script-

```
os_name=$(cat /etc/os-release | awk -F '=' '/^NAME/{print $2}' | awk '{print $1}' | tr -d '"')

if [ "$os_name" == "Ubuntu" ]
then
        echo "system is ubuntu"
        os_versionid=$(cat /etc/os-release | awk -F '=' '/^VERSION_ID/{print $2}' | awk '{print $1}' | tr -d '"')

        case $os_versionid in
                "14.04" )
                        echo "os version is 14.04"
                        sudo apt-get update
                        ;;

                "16.04" )
                        echo "os version is 16.04"
                        sudo apt-get update
                        ;;

                "18.04" )
                        echo "os version is 18.04"
                        sudo apt update
                        ;;
        esac
elif [ "$os_name" == "CentOS" ]
then
        echo "system is centos"
        sudo yum update
else
        echo "system is $os_name"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use python

```
if ! python -c "exec(\"import platform\nexit ('centos' not in platform.linux_distribution()[0].lower())\")" ; then
   echo "It is not CentOS distribution, ignoring CentOS setup"
   exit 0
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Using this command works in CentOS, Ubuntu and Debian:
`grep "^NAME=" /etc/os-release |cut -d "=" -f 2 | sed -e 's/^"//' -e 's/"$//'`

In Debian it yields `Debian GNU/Linux`, in Ubuntu it yields `Ubuntu` and in CentOS it yields `CentOS Linux`.

The benefit of using grep, cut and sed instead of gawk is clear: Debian does not have gawk installed by default, so you cannot rely on it on random Debian box.

Answer (score 0):

Following [@terdon's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/459425/618353), I like the simple solution below:

```
gcc --version | grep "Red Hat"
if [ "$?" -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "OK, on centos"
fi

gcc --version | grep Ubuntu
if [ "$?" -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "OK, on Ubuntu"
fi
```

Answer (score -1):

#### Awk  is supported on almost every nix system so this should be enough so we not have to care about all tools.

```
#!/bin/bash

DISTRO="$(awk -F= '/^NAME/{print tolower($2)}' /etc/os-release|awk 'gsub(/[" ]/,x) + 1')"

[[ "${DISTRO}" = "gentoo" || "${DISTRO}" = "ubuntu" ]] && \
awk 'BEGIN{print "'${DISTRO}'"}' || \
awk 'BEGIN{print "Unknown distro..."}'
```

#### Perl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Linux::Distribution qw(distribution_name);
if(my $distro = distribution_name) { print "Distro: $distro\n"; } else { print "Unkown distro...n\n";}
```